# How to get a proper production build with svelte-kit?

Tags: sveltekit

Im trying out svelte-kit, and it looks promising. However, I get confused when I run npm run build. I used to get a "dist" folder with a index.html file + som javascript that I could just deploy to a web server. With svelte-kit, I get a .svelte-kit folder with lot of strange files within, but no index.html. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the adapters https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters

Comment: Thanks. Could you recomend what adapter I should choose to just get the most basic deployable file collection? Like what I get with "vanilla" svelte?

Comment: There is no such thing, but what you probably mean is output without a server component, which would be `@sveltejs/adapter-static`.

Comment: Yes, I want to just copy everything and put them in the root of a Jetty server. But I will check out the other possible scenarios as well, currently the concept of an extra "server component" is a bit of a mystery for me.